# RewriteRule not working for proxy

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to proxy all request containing word `api/` to some other server.
In my .htaccess I have the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ http://original.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, when I am trying to send some requests that would normally work on the server that I am pointing to, like:

```
mypage.com/api/users
```

Says its not found. However, If I go to:

```
original.com/api/users
```

It will return proper response.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is shown .htaccess located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this directive:

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ http://original.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Which tells Apache to redirect all  requests that start with `api/`  to `http://original.com/`  using external redirect(`Location` header) with HTTP response code of `301` (Permanent redirect - cached by browsers).

There is no mention of proxy (`P` flag) in that line.What you need is this:

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ http://original.com/api/$1  [L,P]
```

P.S: clear your  browser's cache before testing this.